# Access SQL Syntax for Cross-Table Count

Tags: sql, select

I have what may be a simple SQL syntax question but I've been scratching my head over it for weeks now and it's abstract enough that I'm having trouble hunting down the correct search in Google.

Let us assume that I have three tables: Users and Bookings:

```
Users:
UserID    Name
1         Adam
2         Bob
3         Charlie

Bookings:
BookingID    UserID    MeetingID
1            1         1
2            2         1
3            2         2
4            3         2
```

The query that I'm looking to create will tell me how many other users each user has shared a meeting ID with. In my example:

```
Output:
UserID      Co-Meeters
1           1
2           2
3           1
```

As in the example, users 1 and 3 only had one co-meeter (in this case "2") and user 2 had two co-meeters (1 and 3).

I'm sorry if my description isn't terribly clear, but I'm trying to strip out the needless complication from other intersecting tables and fields that don't really affect the syntax I'm looking for. My initial thought was to use "Group By", but since Bookings is a many-to-many (in terms of the fields I'm looking at) I can't make the logic work.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
select u.userid, iif(isnull(x.others), 0, x.others) as [Co-Meeters] 
from users u 
  left join bookings b on u.userid = b.userid
  left join (
    select meetingid, count(*) as others from bookings where userid <> u.userid
  ) x on b.meetingid = x.meetingid
order by 1
```